# How to access the AST generated by the Q# compiler?

Tags: c#, abstract-syntax-tree, quantum-computing, q#

**Background**

Part of the project I'm working on requires me to analyze Q# source code and perform specific actions when certain syntax elements are encountered. For example, say I'd like to count how many different gate types are used throughout the program. Now, this could be implemented by walking the Abstract Syntax Tree of the program and performing actions based on the current syntax node.

**What I've tried**

I've started by analyzing the [qsharp-compiler](https://github.com/microsoft/qsharp-compiler) repository, however, the inner workings of the compiler lack online documentation and browsing all the C# and F# sources can be really tedious.

Of course, I could write my own parser for the language, but that would probably be an overkill for the task at hand. There *has to* be a way to extract the AST from inside of the compiler.

**The question**

Is there a way to compile Q# source code using the Q# compiler programmatically (from C# or F#), and extract the internal AST?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly possible to compile Q# source code programmatically. This is particularly useful if you want to repeatedly update a compilation - you can add/remove/edit (parts of) the sources and references in memory, and query all kinds of useful information about the current state of the compilation that e.g. an IDE cares about (like e.g. which symbols are defined at a particular location in a certain file).

However, if you just want to process the AST for a Q# compilation, then there is a much easier way! The Q# compiler has an extensibility mechanism that I believe fits your need perfectly.
This [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/qsharp/extending-the-q-compiler/) gives a brief overview over the feature.
There is also an [example](https://github.com/microsoft/qsharp-compiler/tree/master/examples/CompilerExtensions) for an extension on the compiler repo. This [readme](https://github.com/microsoft/qsharp-compiler/tree/master/src/QuantumSdk) (and possibly [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/qsharp-compiler/tree/master/examples/CompilerExtensions/ExtensionPackage)) may also come in handy. I believe this answers half of your question, namely how to easily get access to the built AST.

The other half of the question according to my interpretation is how to conveniently analyze or transform the AST. For that there is also a mechanism provided; the syntax tree transformation framework. That framework consists of a couple of classes that define the walk/transformation for different kinds of nodes, as well as a wrapping class that plugs it all together.

Rather than starting by looking at the definition of the transformations, it is probably more intuitive to just look at some examples that use it. An example that is pretty close to what you want to do can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/qsharp-compiler/blob/master/examples/CompilerExtensions/CustomExtension/ListIdentifiers.cs). The implemented transformation adds a comment to each callable listing all identifiers used within the callable. It is invoked as as part of a compilation step (see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/qsharp-compiler/blob/0b8cdb498711feddb211dcb0e83733e28c3a3f49/examples/CompilerExtensions/CustomExtension/Optimize.cs#L73)) that is defined in the example I already linked above.

There are a couple of other good examples for simple transformations that are a bit farther from what you want to do, but should give you an idea how the whole setup works if you are interested: [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/qsharp-compiler/blob/master/src/QsCompiler/Transformations/Attributes.cs) allows to attach attributes to callables, and [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/qsharp-compiler/blob/master/src/QsCompiler/Transformations/Conjugations.cs) is used to inline conjugations (pattern of the form U*VU).

Last but not least, the [Gitter](https://gitter.im/qsharp-community/community) for the [Q# community](https://qsharp.community/) can possibly also be a good resource to engage as you work.